# Adding a custom function to formValidation.js configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, formvalidation-plugin

I have the following configuration which validates a form when a submit button is pressed:

```
 $('#myForm').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    excluded: [':disabled'],
    icon: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        title: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Title is required (max 128 characters)'
                }
            }
        },
        rating: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: // Call function here? check for 0
                }
            }
        }            
    }
});
```

The rating field is a slider, whereby the user can choose a value between 0 and 5

[image]

By default it is 0, so when I press submit it validates as valid, so I need to create a custom function which will check its value if it's 0 then return invalid otherwise true.

The html is as follows:

```
 <input id="Rating" name="rating" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="" /> <span id="rate" style="margin-left:5%">0 / 5</span>
```

How the HTML looks when its render, and referenced bootstrap-slider.js

```
<input id="Rating" type="text" data-slider-value="" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-id="ex1Slider" name="rating" data-fv-field="rating" style="display: none;" data="value: '0'" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try the [greaterThan](http://formvalidation.io/validators/greaterThan/) validator:

```
rating: {
    validators: {
        greaterThan: {
            value: 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't even no that existed, I've only been playing around with formValidation.js for the past few hours thanks for the link.  Though I have tried that but it returns valid? I am using this slider http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle to show that result? I'm pretty confident the syntax here is correct.

Comment: The syntax is correct yet, but its down to how the HTML is rendered after I have linked it to the bootstrap-slider.js I have updated my question with the rendered HTML you will see at the end a field called value this particular field gets changed everytime the user slides the slider with its new value i.e 0 - 5

Comment: To be honest, I would need to see  your code in action. But try to make `data-slider-value=0`

Comment: apologies It's working, my cache had a funny 5 minutes, last question though as I'm keen to know going back to the original question do you know how to create a custom function?

Comment: You just need to read the API, I've never used this library before: http://formvalidation.io/validators/callback/